# How to get fully expanded gnu make variable value

Tags: variables, macros, makefile, expand, expansion

I'm trying pass the fully evaluated value of a recursive make variables to a $(shell ...).  I've tried many ways, including a macro to compute the final value myself, but have not had success.

I'm getting the intermediate variable syntax in my shell instead of the fully expanded recursive variable value.

```
VAR1 ?= var1_value
VAR2 ?= var2_value1 var2_value2
VAR3 ?= $(VAR1)
VARLIST := VAR1 VAR2 VAR3

quote     = $(if $(call ne,$(words $(1)),1),"$(1)",$(1))
GENVARS1  = $(foreach v,$(1),set $(v) $(call quote,$(value $(v)));)
SHELLVARLIST = $(shell echo $(call GENVARS1,$(VARLIST)))

shelltest :
    @echo "--->Executing recipe for shelltest"
    @echo "VAR3 is $(VAR3)"
    $(call GENVARS,$(VARLIST))
    @echo "SHELLVARLIST = $(SHELLVARLIST)"
```

In an ordinary dereference (at least in a recipe), the variable is fully expanded.  However, when passed to macro as an argument, it does not.  Is there any way to get the fully expanded value into a macro argument?

Here's the result when running make:

```
bash-4.1$ make -f test_expand.mk shelltest
/bin/sh: VAR1: command not found
--->Executing recipe for shelltest
VAR3 is var1_value
set VAR1 var1_value; set VAR2 var2_value1 var2_value2; set VAR3 $(VAR1);
/bin/sh: VAR1: command not found
SHELLVARLIST = set VAR1 var1_value
```

As you can see, $(VAR3) does not get passed as "var1_value" but instead gets passed as the literal "$(VAR1)".

Any hints or pointers would be most welcome.  This is hair-pullingly frustrating (and I have so little left... :-o)

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: It's very unclear what the author wanted. This is not a MWE.

Comment: Not sure who down voted this or why you would have posted your comment, given that it was clear enough to have elicited an immediate and accepted answer, almost 4 years ago.

Comment: Maybe you're right that only my understanding is poor. However, why do you call your target "shellvartest" instead of "shelltest" used in the command line later?

Comment: Because I was trying to pass both expanded variables and unexpanded variables to a child shell process.  The example posted was minimized to focus on the particular question.

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question is a bit complicated for my understanding of Makefiles. Do I understand from your answer right that the name of the target is "shellvartest :" (with var), while you invoke that with "make -f test_expand.mk shelltest" (without var)?

Comment: EDIT: corrected make target name to 'shelltest'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly telling make to NOT expand the variable, by using the `$(value $(V))` construct.  That's what the `value` function does: avoids expansion.

If you want expansion, get rid of the `value` function.  Why did you add it there in the first place?

```
GENVARS1  = $(foreach v,$(1),set $(v) $(call quote,$(v));)
```

*ETA*

Sorry, if you want the expansion of the value as a variable name, you need to add an extra level of `$(...)` to expand it:

```
GENVARS1  = $(foreach v,$(1),set $(v) $(call quote,$($(v)));)
```

The inner `$(v)` expands to the name of the variable such as `VAR3`, so then the outer `$(...)` will be `$(VAR3)` and expand to the value of the `VAR3` variable.

Comment: Because when I use the code you suggest, I still do not get the desired outcome: (How do I get the formatting in the comment box?)<br>[code]       bash-4.1$ make -f test_expand.mk shellvartest
    --->Executing recipe for shelltest
    VAR3 is var1_value
    set VAR1 VAR1; set VAR2 VAR2; set VAR3 VAR3;
    SHELLVARLIST =

Comment: Also, I may have oversimplified the problem statement but I want to gain some understanding here before exposing the true complexity of what I'm ultimately going for.  The GENVARS call is actually in a $(shell ...) inside a multi-line macro.

Comment: You cannot use paragraph formatting in a comment, only per-word formatting.  If you have something more complex to say you should edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks MadScientist.  It seems I had lost my way (mind?) in a maze of macros and function calls, and tried the $(value ...) function by mistake.  I can't even recall the problem I was trying to solve when I made that change.  I had the syntax you suggested prior to that.